# Python misbehaves with average of equal numbers: NaN output

Tags: python, arrays, average, nan, try-except

Python is driving me mad. It is able to evaluate the average of the elements in a vector, unless they are all equal. This is the output I get for size-2 vectors:

```
Energy values to average out at kbt= 0.05  :
[-499.99375, -499.99375]
The average energy at kbt= 0.05 is equal to nan
Energy values to average out at kbt= 0.2  :
[-421.3611875, -426.6630875]
The energy at kbt= 0.2 is equal to -424.0852007562413
```

The function evaluating the average I am using is this:

```
def weighted_average(vector,variances):
"""
This function evaluates the average of values stored in 'vector' (which are supposed to be 
averages themselves)
weighing them with variances according to the well known formula. It also evaluates the error.
When the variances are zero, the weighted average cannot be calculated. In that case the 
function outputs just
the average of the averages and one of the variances (which could also be zero) divided by the 
number of averages.
:param vector: vector of values
:param variances: vector of variances
:return: avg, err
"""
vector_size=len(vector)
sum_of_inverse_variances=0
avg=0
try:                                            #we need to put this try/except thing here,
    for i in range(0,vector_size):              #because it could happen that we have troubles
        sum_of_inverse_variances=sum_of_inverse_variances+1/variances[i]     #evaluating the 
                                                               #error on the weighted average.
        avg=avg+vector[i]/variances[i]       #One variance could be zero, and you would have
    avg=avg/sum_of_inverse_variances                              #division by zero problems.
    err=np.sqrt(1/sum_of_inverse_variances)
except:                                 #If the code encounters a division by zero problem,
    for i in range(0,vector_size):      #it outputs just the average of the averages and as
        avg=avg+vector[i]               #error it takes the variance on the first average
    avg=avg/float(vector_size)   #and divides it by the number of averages. This corresponds
    err=np.sqrt(variances[0]/float(vector_size))       #to the case in which all variances are 
                                                       #equal.
return avg,err
```

Does this have anything to do with try/except statement?

Comment: Can you please provide an example input that produces the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Trying the function out on its own, it works. If I define:                 
`a=[1,2,3,5]
a_var=[0.1,0.022,0.43,0.51]
b=[2,2,2,2]
b_var=[0,0,0,0]`                                                                                                                   This is the output I get:                                                                                                      `Weighted average of a:  1.9700027062097105  error on w.a.:  0.12937908605695347
Weighted average of b:  2.0  error on w.a.:  0.0`

Comment: But if I use the function in the script - by the way it is inside a `for` loop that is parallelized - for one case in which the input vectors are, respectively, [r,r,r,r,r...] (r being some number) and [0,0,0,0,0...], I get a NaN output...